# Using Macros to send email to specific recipients

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to send email reminder to specific recipient with their associated userIDs stored in an Excel worksheet. The email will only send to the recipient if they have not completed the survey. (Cells(iCounter,3))

MailDest is where all the recipients' email are located. DGName contains all the associated userIDs of the recipient. One recipient can have more than one userID.

The problem is that all the userIDs (DGName) of recipients are generated in every single email that is sent to them.

How should I edit my codes so that it will send the email to the recipients associated email and their userIDs?

**EDIT**
Here are the codes:

```
Sub SendReminderMail()

Dim OutLookApp As Object    
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object    
Dim iCounter As Integer    
Dim MailDest As String    
Dim DGName As String

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")    
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutLookMailItem    
    MailDest = ""    
    For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(5))

        If MailDest = "" And Cells(iCounter, 3) = "" Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 5).Value
            DGName = Cells(iCounter, 1).Value
        ElseIf MailDest <> "" And Cells(iCounter, 3) = "" Then
            MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 5)
            DGName = DGName & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 1)
        End If

    Next iCounter

    .BCC = MailDest
    .Subject = "W2K16 update on Cloudworkplace Desktop Group"
    .HTMLBody = "Dear ~Whoever ," & "<br/><br/>" & DGName & "<br/><br/>" & " ~Message"
    .send
```

In this sample, if "Feedback" Column is empty, it will trigger the macro to send the reminder email to recipient.

[Sample Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyKjQ.png)

Comment: Why double line spacing in VBA code?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I am not familiar with the interface of Stackoverflow, so I put the codes in ` ` and separate them with line spacing.

Comment: Paste your code then select it all and hit ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the moment you send 1 email to multiple addresses (BCC). So you need to change the code to send multiple individual mails (1 mail each address).

Therefore just put the code to send the mail within the for loop:

```
With OutLookMailItem       
    For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(16))
        If Cells(iCounter, 14) = "" Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 16).Value
            DGName = Cells(iCounter, 12).Value
            .To = MailDest
            .Subject = "W2K16 update on Cloudworkplace Desktop Group"
            .HTMLBody = "Dear ~Whoever ," & "<br/><br/>" & DGName & "<br/><br/>" & " ~Message"
            .send
        End If
    Next iCounter
```

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, thanks a lot for the response!! Just another quick question, what can I do if I would like to display multiple DGName in the same email?

Comment: @AshKetchum I don't understand what sense that makes. 1 mail address corresponds to 1 name. If not you must be much more specific.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, sorry for any inconvenience. The variable "DGName" are actually userIDs that is associated with the recipients. So basically, one recipient can have many different DGName registered under the same email. What I wish to achieve is that the reminder I am going to send will consist of the different DGName associated with the same email address. Hopes that will clarify your doubts.

Comment: @AshKetchum Well this is a completely different question now. This cannot be answered in a short comment. Nor can it be answered without knowing how your data looks like. Therefore I suggest to ask a new question including sample data or screenshots.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score -1):

As I review your code found that DGName variable needs to make blank string after looping again into For 1st loop

I am write this in solution because unable to write a comment.
the code something like below

```
Sub SendReminderMail()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim MailDest As String
Dim DGName As String

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutLookMailItem
    MailDest = ""

    For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(16))
    DGName = "" 'see here

        If MailDest = "" And Cells(iCounter, 14) = "" Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 16).Value
            DGName = Cells(iCounter, 12).Value
        ElseIf MailDest <> "" And Cells(iCounter, 14) = "" Then
            MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 16)
            DGName = DGName & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 12)
        End If

    Next iCounter

    .BCC = MailDest
    .Subject = "W2K16 update on Cloudworkplace Desktop Group"
    .HTMLBody = "Dear ~Whoever ," & "<br/><br/>" & DGName & "<br/><br/>" & " ~Message"
    .send
```

Comment: Hi @Dinesh Pawar. Using the solution you have provided, the emails that are sent out do not have DGName in them. How should I proceed?